# Regex in Javascript to remove nested paragraphs

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
<p style="text-align: right;">
   <p style="text-align: center;">
      <p style="text-align: left;">
         <p style="text-align:center;">
            leave this content
         </p>
      </p>
   </p>
</p>
<br>
```

save the content and the last paragraph with the style that has been applied,
which is

`<p style="text-align: right;">`

Comment: expected output please you write on question.

Comment: it is outside, and it can be more than two, three

Comment: expected output: <p style="text-align: right;">leave this content</p><br>

Comment: Use an HTML parser not a regex. A regex is the wrong tool: 1. they are not good – without extensions that JS's regex engine does not have – at matching grouping structures, 2. there are [consequences](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/67392).

Comment: It is unfortunate that nested paragraphs are *invalid HTML* else jQuery would be able to do this easily :(

Comment: how can it be done using jquery?

Comment: how to use html parser? any links please

Answer (score 0):

For the concrete case that you provided try this simple code:

```
var elementToKeep = $('selectorToParagraph');

elementToKeep.html(elementToKeep.text());
```

For more universal cases you'll have to use an HTML parser.

Comment: ok, and how should I keep that content wrapped with last paragraph

Comment: the problem is that rich editor reads wrong the styles of nested paragraph. Especially if it is wrapped with other html tags

Answer (score 0):

Regex is

```
<p style="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/p>
```

then try this

```
content = content.replace("<p style="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/p>","<p style="$1">$2</p>");
```

Comment: it leaves me with closing p tags i.e </p></p></p>

Answer (score 0):

I try this

```
<p(?: [^>]+)?>((?:(?!<\/?p[ >]).)*)<\/p>
```

change the style as right for para. This only possible in regex.

**SEE DEMO:** http://regex101.com/r/dJ5nB1/1